# If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then there is a limit ordinal $\mu$ with $\alpha < \mu$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

There is this theorem that states:
If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then there is a limit ordinal $\mu$ with $\alpha < \mu$.

The definition of limit ordinal is just "an ordinal which is a limit", but a better reformulation of this definition is:
Let $\lambda$ be a non-zero ordinal. $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal if and only if for all ordinal $\alpha$, if $\alpha<\lambda$ then $\alpha^+<\lambda$. ($\alpha^+$ is the successor ordinal of $\alpha$)

I don't understand how that theorem makes sense, the book I'm reading gives the proof as an exercise (which I can't do) so I can't even see why it's true. If for example I have the ordinal $1=\{\emptyset\}$ what is a limit ordinal for this? Is it $\omega$ for example (or $2\omega$, $3\omega$ etc)? Is this what it means?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then $\alpha+\omega$ is a limit ordinal bigger than $\alpha$ (so are $\alpha+\omega\cdot 2$ or $\alpha+\gamma$ for any limit $\gamma$)

Comment: Which part seems confusing to you? Every limit ordinal is bigger than $1$, so any limit ordinal at all will work. In general, if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha+\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: @tomasz Yeah and is that all it says? For example if i have the ordinal $\omega$ the limit ordinal for this is $\omega+\omega$, correct?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio: That is one example. Another is $\omega_7^{\omega_{10}}$.

Comment: @tomasz Well yeah, but for the theorem to be true you only need one though. Thank you by the way! I was overcomplicating things.. now i understand thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ordinals $\omega$, $\omega2$, $\omega3$ etc. work for $\alpha=1$.

In general, for any $\alpha$, the ordinal $\alpha+\omega$ works (or, more generally, the ordinal $\alpha+\beta$, where $\beta>0$ is a limit ordinal).

As a side remark: the ordinals $\omega$, $2\omega$, $3\omega$ etc. are all equal.

Comment: What do you mean with "are all equal"? You mean they're all limit ordinals for $\alpha$?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio What he means is that they are **equal**. In general ordinal multiplication is not commutative, and $2\omega\ne\omega2$. In fact $\omega2=\omega+\omega\gt\omega$ but $2\omega=\omega=3\omega=4\omega$.

Comment: Oh okay! I didn't know it they're gonna explain ordinal numbers arithmetic in the next chapter, thank you!